# Can we recover a vector from one element of resulted vector after multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have a matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.5000 + 0.5000i & 0.5000 - 0.5000i\\ 
 0.5000 - 0.5000i & 0.5000 + 0.5000i
\end{bmatrix}$  multiplied with a column containing a complex number and its conjugate, as below:

$y  = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_2
\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
 0.5000 + 0.5000i & 0.5000 - 0.5000i\\ 
 0.5000 - 0.5000i & 0.5000 + 0.5000i
\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
s\\ 
s'
\end{bmatrix}$

I am wondering if we can recover $s$ from only $y_1$ or $y_2$. I mean,  as long as the vector $s$ is only containing a complex number with its conjugate, so we can estimate $s$ from only $y_1$. I In other words, $s$ is supposed to be included in $y_1$, and also included in $y_2$. Is that right ?  But, I don't know how can I estimate $s$ based on only $y_1$.

Comment: Hint : [invert the matrix X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_2_%C3%97_2_matrices).

Comment: @KurtG. I mean recovering $s$ based only on $y_1$ OR $y_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $s=s_r+is_i$ and $s'=s_r-is_i$ then (if I did not make any mistake):
$$y_1=\frac14(s_r+is_i+is_r-s_i+s_r-is_i-is_r-s_i)=\frac12 (s_r-s_i)\\
y_2=\frac12(s_r+s_i)$$
Notice that neither $y_1$ or $y_2$ alone allows you to find both $s_r$ and $s_i$.

Comment: I think $y_1 = s_r - s_i$ and $y_2 = s_r+s_i$. thank you